# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'snp.routing'

Tags: django, django-channels

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'snp.routing.application'
```

routing.py:

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter ({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter (
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

i'm having this error while imporing ASGI_APPLICATION, how can i fix it

raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'snp.routing'

Comment: This line should be: ASGI_APPLICATION = 'snp.asgi.application'

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

import appname.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack((
            URLRouter(
                appname.routing.webscoket_urlpatterns
            )
        ))
    )
})
```

TRY THIS:)